# How can I add a new Boolean property to System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oop

Is it possible to do this without inheritance? I'm working on a very large existing WebForms project and I don't want to amend every instance of the various used WebControls to use a new child class that adds the new Bool Property.

Just can't seem to find a clear answer on this.

Comment: How you want to change a used class without modifying it? Your question is too general. You don't show any code, not a single sample control. We have no information about the `Boolean` property and why you need to add it(maybe we know a different way). So it's hard to give an answer

Comment: See this type of "short cutting" question quite frequently.  Honestly, in my experience in the time you've taken in asking the question, waiting for the response, implementing the response, debugging the response you could of just implemented it properly and done a find and replace

Comment: *"Is it possible to do this without inheritance?"*. Of course it isn't.